# Make header scroll to div in another component file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, header, navigation

I have this app that in the end only have 1 page. My current file structure is divided per section. I want to make the header if clicked scroll to a certain section (that is on another component,  they're not on the same file).

This is the code in the file that contains all component.

```
<Header />
<Banner />
<Description />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project with **'npm build'** your files will get minified and a single JS file will get produced, which contains all of your component codes.so no need to think about an issue because of codes in multiple files.

I think you have to give *absolute css positioning* to Header component and display where ever you want.